# optimal data structure to store million of pixels in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have several images and after some basic processing and contour detection I want to store the detected pixels locations and their adjacent neighbours values into a Python Data Structure. I settled for **numpy.array**

The pixel locations from each Image are retrieved using:

```
locationsPx = cv2.findNonZero(SomeBWImage)
```

which will return an array of the shape (NumberOfPixels,1L,2L) with :

```
print(locationsPx[0]) : array([[1649,    4]])
```

for example.

My question is: is it possible to store this double array on a single column in another array? Or should I use a list and drop the array all together?

**note:  the dataset of images might increase so the dimensions of my chose data structure will not be only huge, but also variable**

EDIT: or maybe numpy.array is not good idea and Pandas Dataframe is better suited? I am open to suggestion from those who have more experience in this.

Comment: Or as [`sparse matrices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html)?

Comment: @Divakar why would it be more preferable than lists or numpy arrays?

Comment: Biggest advantage would be saving on memory as contour info by its very nature is *sparsey* and still being able to use scipy/numpy ufuncs.

Comment: What type of data structure is "optimal" depends a great deal on what you plan on doing with the data. What's your motivation for wanting to store these values in "a single column in another array"? What don't you like about the current format? Sparse matrices are not going to be any more memory-efficient than storing your pixel indices in an `(npixels, 1, 2)` dense array, although there may be performance advantages depending on what computations you want perform with your data.

Comment: @ali_m The goal of the pixel extraction is to use them as input for a machine learning algortihm (for which one, I haven't figured that out yet). So at the same time I want to store the pixels locations & grayscale values in a tabular data format AND be able to identify later what is the original image file they come from. So I was thinking I need some named columns ( like in pd.DataFrame) so I don't mess up what is in each column. It might be that my initial question is badly formulated, apologies.

Comment: I would use something like a list of [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), where each field has two uint fields containing the pixel row and column indices and a third (int or float?) field to contain the pixel values. Structured arrays are trivially easy to convert to pandas DataFrames if you prefer. If you have a large amount of these arrays then you will probably want to write your data to disk, e.g. using an [h5py variable length array](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/special.html#vlen).

Comment: I think the trickier issue will be dealing with the fact that your input vectors have variable lengths, but you haven't specified the task or the algorithm you're using, so I assume this question is just about storage.

Comment: @ali_m Structured arrays worked just fine for storing a lot of pixel values. Do you think it's a good idea to store also raw data image alongside the pixel values? I tried to use structured arrays to do that, ofc it crashed. So perhaps another structure is better, or storing images is altogether a bad idea. I am not sure about the algorithm. Still exploring there. All I am trying to achieve now is feature extraction.

Comment: @ali_m is there a better way to append data to a structured array than numpy.append() which needs conversion of data to dtype?

Comment: *"Do you think it's a good idea to store also raw data image alongside the pixel values?"* - I don't know, you tell me. Do you *need* the raw images? They will take up a lot more storage space than the pixel locations and values.

Comment: *"is there a better way to append data to a structured array than numpy.append()"* - appending to a numpy array is slow and memory-intensive, since it requires making a copy of the entire array. If you want to join many arrays it's much better to accumulate them in a list, then concatenate the whole list in one go (e.g. using `np.hstack`). In your case I would just keep them in a list where each element corresponds to an image (or maybe write them to a variable-length h5py array?).

Comment: Check the [`np.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) function :)

Comment: Not really a direct answer, but take a look at Dask for Python. If you store the data on the disk and only load it in memory in small chunks, the data structure might not be as important anymore.

Comment: IMO, list is the way to go in your case. Make sure to use the right datatype (int8/int16/int32) for storing indexes. In some  cases, it might be easier to store the image with 1bit/pixel to keep only the boundary info.

Comment: Have a look at http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/ this also comes with dask support.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays are great for computation. They are not great for storing data if the size of the data keeps changing. As ali_m pointed out, all forms of array concatenation in numpy are inherently slow. Better to store the arrays in a plain-old python list:

```
coordlist = []
coordlist.append(locationsPx[0])
```

Alternatively, if your images have names, it might be attractive to use a `dict` with the image names as keys:

```
coorddict = {}
coorddict[image_name] = locationsPx[0]
```

Either way, you can readily iterate over the contents of the list:

```
for coords in coordlist:
```

or

```
for image_name, coords in coorddict.items():
```

And `pickle` is a convenient way to store your results in a file:

```
import pickle
with open("filename.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(coordlist, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

(or same with `coorddict` instead of coordlist).
Reloading is trivially easy as well:

```
with open("filename.pkl", "rb") as f:
    coordlist = pickle.load(f)
```

There are some security concerns with `pickle`, but if you only load files you have created yourself, those don't apply.

If you find yourself frequently adding to a previously pickled file, you might be better off with an alternative back end, such as `sqlite`.